# Javascript error when destroying Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Trying to change on the go the title and content of a bootstrap Popover, I am having some trouble.

I am getting this issue when destroying a popover content in a selector.

The error is this

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'data[option]()')
```

The piece of code is this:

```
$("#test_name-" + json.test_id).popover('destroy');
```

I get the error in that line. I have checked that `$("#test_name-" + json.test_id)` really contains a Popover.

Edited: I solved it thanks to the comments. I wasn't using the latest versions of Bootstrap. Once upgraded to 2.1.0, all seems to work perfect.

Important! In this new version, you need to set trigger to "hover" as it is by default to "click".

Thanks a lot

Pedro

Comment: Can you provide more details, a fiddle page, live example or some debug information?

Comment: Which version of jQuery and Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Thanks Joao, I just edited the question to show the solution.

Comment: @ElPiter, you should post the solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Version 2.1.0 fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to the comments. I wasn't using the latest versions of Bootstrap. Once upgraded to 2.1.0, all seems to work perfect.